# Finding strange in using .env file value

Tags: reactjs

I am encountering something strange here and hope to find out if I have missed anything. Here is the thing, I have a .env file with this value here:SITE_URL=http://localhost:5000 and when I tried console.log(process.env.SITE_URL), it returned undefined. But the strange thing is when I changed .env file value to REACT_APP_FETCH_URL=http://localhost:5000 and did a console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL), it returned http://localhost:5000.

I am not sure what is going on? Any help greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is most likely due to how you're building your app. Something has to be taking the values from the env and adding them to the node environment variables. This can be a manual process in in something like a webpack config, or done by a framework automatically. Are you using any framework?

Comment: hi Brian Thompson, Sorry, I did not mention that the .env file is in the React project folder and I am using it for the Axios call  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL)
    const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/auth/register', registerData). Does ReactJS has certain reserved keywords? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using `create-react-app`. In CRA you need to prefix your environment variables with `REACT_APP_` in order for them to be accessible under `provess.env`.

You can check documentation about it here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: So I see. Thanks Jayce44